# Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser: session drops out on resume

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I made an application for my own website that just navigates to it's homepage with a WebBrowser control.

Then I do login to my website and switch to an another application by holding down to back button, but the problem is that when I switch back to my application, it reloads the page and logs out of my account that I just logged in only two minutes ago.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this, which may be what you're looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx

> If the user returns to the application by pressing the Back button or
>   by using the Task Switcher, the app instance resumes. Because the app
>   was preserved in memory, the app quickly resumes in the same state it
>   was when the user navigated away. This process is called Fast App
>   Switching (FAS). If the app is suspended and the user relaunches the
>   app, such as by tapping on the app name in the app list or tapping the
>   app’s primary Start Tile, by default the old instance of the app is
>   terminated and a brand new instance of the app is created. This
>   process is slower than resuming a suspended app and provides a
>   different user experience. Windows Phone 8 introduces the ability for
>   apps to request that user actions that would typically relaunch the
>   app, such as tapping the app’s Start Tile, instead resume the
>   suspended instance of the suspended app instance, if one exists. This
>   feature is called Fast Resume.